# "Pain in the neck" and similar expressions

Tags: phrases, expressions, slang, offensive-language

Are there any other expressions equivalent in meaning to "pain in the neck" that mention another part of the body (e.g, "pain in the ass")?

How would you rate each of those expressions (including the ones just mentioned) in a scale of being offensive or vulgar? In other words, which ones would you use in an informal context, but without going too far?

*(this question is probably mistagged)*

Comment: I'm afraid questions such as this, where all answers will be equally valid, are considered not constructive. please read the [faq] for more information.

Comment: @MattЭллен Sorry about that, could you please point me to the specific FAQ? I was reading them just before asking and I could not find anything relevant. My idea here is to have a collection of equivalent expressions, and look for a consensus among different people w.r.t. the vulgarity of such expressions.

Comment: @MarcoLeogrande The problem is that the Q&A format is not well-suited to generating lists, due to the difficulty in *maintaining* lists and constantly re-judging which answer or list is most correct over the lifetime of the question on the site (potentially many years). They are also never definitively complete, so they attract a constant stream of new, low-quality answers as passers-by feel like they have a list item to add.

Comment: specifically [faq#dontask]

Comment: @MattЭллен and SevenSidedDie, I see your point now, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Questions where every answer is equally valid should be closed or moved to the Community Wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a few on google, and sorted them by least offensive.

He's a

- headache.
- an eyesore. (not equivalent, but has a body part)
- pain in the neck.
- pain in the rear
- pain in the rear end.
- pain in the butt.
- pain in the back side.
- pain in the arse.
- pain in the ass.

I would find any below the fourth to be vulgar.

Comment: 'He's a pain in the wallet' (right next to many a man's heart, of course) is sometimes used.